# Apply image filter

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to use some of the fabric image filters, but when i apply a filter the image disappears. Acutally it´s just the code from the tutorial http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2/.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://applyfilters.fm/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/IMG_0289-e1405013078402.jpg', function(img) {
img.scale(0.5);
img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());
img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
canvas.add(img);
});
```

Please be so kind to inform me what my stupid and likely trivial mistake is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check crossOrigin: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#crossOrigin

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I have less reputation, I cannot make comment.

At the tutorial, the image is in same host.
How about using `test.jpg`, not `http://applyfilters.fm/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/IMG_0289-e1405013078402.jpg`?